# Getting class not found exception on EhCacheManager in Spring 4.2

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

Not able to resolve below error:

> Cannot find class [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager]

I am using Spring 4.2.4 and Ehcache 3.1.3.

Maven dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Beans configuration:

```xml
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager">
        <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Not sure what is missing. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What code are you running that you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is not the current problem, you will encounter this once you fix it:

There is currently no native support of Ehcache 3 in Spring. It is only available through the JCache support.

Ehcache 3.x is a breaking change from Ehcache 2.x and packages, class names and configuration formats all have changed.

And thus the `org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager` will not work with Ehcache 3.

I did a [talk on using Ehcache 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSpgLZ1U75g) inside Spring that details the different integration possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, i wasn't aware of the changes for 3.x

Comment: If i want to use ehcache without spring , is there any working example in java ? I tried searching for it but i found one sample code which is on ehache 3.x support site but didnt find any working example

Comment: Added a link to a presentation where I show how to use Ehcache 3.

Comment: Thanks that was useful

Answer (score 2):

The dependency you are missing is this:

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
<version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
```

And if you ever find yourself looking for the right dependency upon seeing a `ClassNotFoundException`, your first point should always be this:

[Find dependency by classname](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav)

Comment: Thanks for your help, after the changes it worked, but again i am finding other issues which i guess relates to ehcache 3.x version, as ehcachemanger is not supported in spring